# Shows bottom section of table view at visible view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I know the title is confusing. So I explain what I expect.

I have 3 sections in my table view. The first section has one or more rows. And second and third sections has only one row. When the first section has more than 4 rows the next sections going to be visible by scrolling table view bottom.

But I need these sections be visible in this case.

Actually I need show these sections at the bottom of the visible frame when first section has more than 4 rows!

Is it possible ?

Comment: I guess it's not possible bcoz table view have sticky header by default

Answer (score 0):

The thing you can do it to display only the 3 first rows of the first section and then when the user starts scrolling, you add the additional cells to the first section while he is scrolling until you've added all of your cell.

Do the opposite when scrolling to top.

Comment: Your solution has a problem, user could not recognize by scrolling the view can see more data.

Comment: Yes, as it'll see the additional sections, and as when it starts to scroll, you directly adds the 4th cell, it should understand that there's more contents. However, I don't see any other applicable solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use two different *TableView* instead of one.
declare first TableView with only one section & seconds TableView with two section with one row each.

for that you need to use *UIViewController* instead of *UITableViewController*.

in this way your bottom TableView Cell always stay visible while first TableView can scroll with more cells.